# Loop Next/Prev Entry Linking

Tags: next-prev

Is there any way to loop the next/prev entry links?

Currently the next link is hidden when you get to the last entry and the prev link is hidden on the first entry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no such built-in functionality exists, to the best of my knowledge. There is a third-party app that claims to do just that, however, [Advanced Prev Next Entry](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/advanced-prev-next-entry):

- Cycle through entries when the end of list is reached.

Comment: Yeah, I've used that plugin before but it seems development stopped on it a long time ago and it throws errors in the latest version of EE 2.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with it. Here's a related thread, perhaps there's more info there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145685/loop-expression-engine-entries

Comment: Actually I tried Advanced Prev Next Entry again and it does work. I was able to fix the PHP error in the plugin and it seems to do the trick!

Comment: Cool! Do you want to share the diff so other people might profit from it as well?

Comment: Sure. On line 1434, I changed function usage() to public static function usage().